# Hibernate Projection - Getting Back Same Object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have a `Person` JPA entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name="age")
  private Integer age;

  @Column(name="hobbies")
  private List<String> hobbies;

  public Person() {};
}
```

Using a `Criteria Query`, is it possible to retrieve a `List<Person>`, but only include each `Person`'s name?

Looking at [Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/), I see that there's a [Criteria#setResultTransformer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setResultTransformer(org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer)) method.

I think that I could transform my results to a `ReducedPerson` class that only contained a name. However, I'd like to select **only** the `Person`'s name, but still get `Person` objects back.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, you'll need to set a `ResultTransformer`. For what I know in this area of hibernate, which is not much, the transformers provided by Hibernate are strict and will fail if a value is missing, so I think you'll need to create your own instance of `ResultTransformer`. I would suggest to look at the code from `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` and make a lenient version of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Constructor Expressions:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#Constructors

You can use your existing Person class (instances returned from your query being, of course, unmanaged) but would however need to a constructor taking the name.

```
SELECT NEW sample.Person(p.name) FROM Person p
```

Answer (score 0):

**Single Projection**

You use an existing `ResultTransformer` like this

```
Criteria query = session.createCriteria(Person.class)
  .setProjection(Projections.property("name").as("name"))
  .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Person.class));
List personNames = query.list();
```

**Multiple Projections**

The example `List` above now contains only Person objects with their name. Regullary, you want also to retrieve the `id` for the persons at least. You can setup multiple properties with this

```
ProjectionList colProjection = Projections.projectionList();
colProjection.add(Projections.property("id"), "id");
colProjection.add(Projections.property("name"), "name");
Criteria query = session.CreateCriteria(Person.class)
  .setProjection(colProjection)
  .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Person.class));
List persons = query.list();
```

Key in this approach is to set the same aliases as their original property names, so we dont need to build our own `ResultTransformer`.